# Concat two ByteBuffers in Java

Tags: java, bytebuffer

How can I concat two ByteBuffers to one ByteBuffer?

The following doesn't work:

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(200);
    bb.allocate(200).put(bb2);
    System.out.println(bb.array().length);
```

The length of `bb` is still `100`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like

```
bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(300).put(bb).put(bb2);
```

should do the job: Create a buffer that is large enough to hold the contents of both buffers, and then use the relative put-methods to fill it with the first and the second buffer. (The `put` method returns the instance that the method was called on, by the way)

Comment: **WARNING :** `position` and `limit` will both be set to `capacity` which is probably **not** what you would expect or want if you are going to process the resulting `ByteBuffer` further. You will want to call `.flip()` to be able to process the entire contents of the returned `ByteBuffer` by adding `.flip();` at the end.

Comment: Yes, `flip()` or `position(0)` (I personally find the latter more readable)

Answer (score 4):

We'll be copying all data. Remember that this is why string concatenation is expensive!

```
public static ByteBuffer concat(final ByteBuffer... buffers) {
    final ByteBuffer combined = ByteBuffer.allocate(Arrays.stream(buffers).mapToInt(Buffer::remaining).sum());
    Arrays.stream(buffers).forEach(b -> combined.put(b.duplicate()));
    return combined;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work (and is cleaner than other proposed solutions) except you probably want to add before the end: `combined.rewind();`

Comment: I agree, it's ambiguous. Should the cursor be at the front or end. Maybe the method name should indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method here

https://github.com/ata4/ioutils/blob/047e401d73c866317af2e12f7803b3ee43eec80a/src/main/java/info/ata4/io/buffer/ByteBufferUtils.java#L289

and for example:

```
  ByteBuffer concat() {
int length = 0;
for (ByteBuffer bb : buffers) {
  bb.rewind();
  length += bb.remaining();
}
ByteBuffer bbNew = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) length);

// put all buffers from list
for (ByteBuffer bb : buffers) {
  bb.rewind();
  bbNew.put(bb);

}
bbNew.rewind();
return bbNew;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because on line3 i.e. `bb.allocate(200).put(bb2);` ,

`bb.allocate(200)` is returning a new Byte buffer (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate(int) ). That is not actually changing `bb` itself. So its still the bytebuffer of capacity 100 from line1.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
//store both ByteBuffer object as an array
byte[] array1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(100).array();
byte[] array2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(200).array();

//create a ByteBuffer which is big enough
ByteBuffer bigenough = ByteBuffer.allocate(array1.length + array2.length);

//put the two arrays in one ByteBuffer
ByteBuffer after1 = bigenough.put(array1, 0, array1.length);
ByteBuffer result = after1.put(array2, array1.length, array2.length);

//print the length of the combined array.
System.out.println(result.array().length);
```

Comment: result has length of 200. I expected to be 300.

Comment: I improved upon the anser. But have you looked into just combining the arrays themselves? Is the ByteBuffer essential to use?